# How can I specify the directory where to create the project for archetype:generate?

Tags: maven, archetypes

I am using `mvn archetype:generate -B ...` to generate a maven project.

It places the generated project in the current working directory.

Can this be customized to place the generated project in a directory I specify? I don't see any options to do so in the command line `--help` menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify a directory for `archetype:generate`, this plugin always targets the current working directory.

The Maven Archetype docs suggest using the `basedir` parameter. Something like this perhaps:

```
mvn archetype:generate 
    -DgroupId=foo 
    -DartifactId=bar 
    -Dbasedir=/some/other/directory
```

But, unfortuntately that doesn't work, even with that parameter specified the archetype is generated into the current working directory. Looking at the Maven Archetype JIRA I can see that there is an open issue for this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-311

This issue has been open since April 2010 and it has been raised against version 2.2.0 of the archetype plugin and I have just verified that this issue still exists with in latest version of the archetype plugin, the following command completed but created `bar` in the current working directory rather than in `/some/other/path` ...

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
    -DinteractiveMode=false 
    -DgroupId=bar 
    -DartifactId=foo 
    -Dbasedir=/some/other/directory
```

So, if you want to use archetype:generate and you want the generated project to exist somewhere else then I think you might have to write a simple script which ...

- Invokes the plugin
- Moves the created directory to your desired location once the plugin has finished running

Comment: i'm on linux so in my case i can just use `pushd .`, then `cd dir_i_wanted_to_export_to`, run the generate,  then `popd` works fine i guess.

Answer (score 3):

-Dbasedir doesn't work.

You could specify output directory by passing -DoutputDirectory=/some/other/directory

Here's the documentation
https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html